# Accessing Interface property in Vspackage from xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am accessing an Interface property (StatusBar) from VSPackage1Package in my xaml.cs page but it always returns null. whereas a string property returns expected value. 
Kindly help me to access StatusBar property on my xaml.cs page.

**VSPackage1Package:**

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
public sealed class VSPackage1Package : Package
    {
        private IVsStatusbar bar;      
        public IVsStatusbar StatusBar
        {
            get
            {
                if (bar == null)
                {
                    bar = GetService(typeof(SVsStatusbar)) as IVsStatusbar;
                }
                return bar;
            }
        }

        public VSPackage1Package()
        {

        }
    }
```

**xaml.cs:**

```
 public partial class TestWindowControl : UserControl
    {
        public void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            VSPackage1Package package = new VSPackage1Package();
            package.StatusBar.SetText("my message");//Here Statusbar is null
        }
    }
```

Comment: try decorate extension with this  [ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.NoSolution)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.SolutionExists)] Link : https://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/blog/visual%20studio%20extensibility/vso-status-inspector-a-walk-through-on-creating-a-vs-extension-to-track-vso-status

Comment: Hi Jophy, I tried this
`using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.NoSolution)]
    [ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.SolutionExists)]
public sealed class VSPackage1Package : Package`
but still I get StatusBar in xaml.cs as null.

Comment: Is there any other way I could use the status bar in other page/class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to access the status bar in xaml.cs page with GetGlobalService

**VSPackage1Package:**

```
 public static IVsStatusbar GetActiveStatusBar()
        {            
            return Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsStatusbar)) as IVsStatusbar;            
        }
```

**xaml.cs:**

```
var statusBar = VSPackage1Package.GetActiveStatusBar();
statusBar.SetText("My message");
```